# Git branch named "--help"

Tags: git

I was running with a detached head and went to create a branch to hold my work. I ran the command `git checkout -b --help` to double check the options for creating a branch.

**Now I have a branched named "--help"**

How do I do anything with this branch? Trying to do anything with it just gives me help messages.

***Details:** git version 1.7.3.5*

Comment: ➜  test git:(master) ✗ git checkout -b --help 
fatal: '--help' is not a valid branch name.

Comment: Which version of Git are you using? I just tried to replicate it and got '--help' is not a valid branch name.

Comment: Have you tried deleting that branch `git branch -d/-D "--help"

Comment: @Arpit yes I have, gives the help message.

Comment: Try `git branch -d -- --help` to delete the branch.

Comment: You can clone your project, and pull only the branches you want. That way you can get rid of it.

Comment: This is anyway just a local branch, you can just ignore it... simply checkout master/other branch and create a new branch from there with some more relevant name. `git checkout master` ; `git checkout -b [branch name]`

Comment: Sorry, but I just have to say that I find this rather amusing. :P

Comment: @Ajedi32 so did I and all the other devs sitting near me. I think this might be a bug in the version of git I have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Command line tools that accept options (`-h`, `--help` etc.) have a special argument that separates non-options from options: `--`

So try this:

```
git branch -d -- --help
```

This effectively makes `--help` a non-option, meaning you can use it as the branch name in your command line parameters.

By the way, this also goes for other commands:

```
cp -- README -r
```

will copy `README` to a new file `-r`.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried putting the name of the branch in quotes on the command line? Like

`git branch -d "--help"`

Comment: Still give the help message